# Saving NSTimer's time to disk on entering background and retrieving on foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, background, nstimer

I want my timer to work in the background, and I have figured the only way to actually do that is to save the time on `appliationDidEnterBackground` and retrieve it with `applicationDidLaunchWithOptions.` My timer uses Core Data and my timeInterval (testTask.timeInterval) is saved after every decrement as so:

```
-(IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender{
    if (timer == nil) {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    } else {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

}
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t
{
    if(testTask.timeInterval == 0)
    {
        if (self.timer)
        {
            [self timerExpired];
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        testTask.timeInterval--;
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(testTask.timeInterval);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                        seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
    timerLabel.text = string;
    NSLog(@"%f", testTask.timeInterval);
}
-(void)timerExpired{
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Time is up";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

These methods are in a detail view controller, which is initialized by this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DetailViewController *detailVC;
    if (![self.detailViewsDictionary.allKeys containsObject:indexPath]){
        detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.detailViewsDictionary setObject:detailVC forKey:indexPath];
        detailVC.context = self.managedObjectContext;
    }else{
        detailVC = self.detailViewsDictionary[indexPath];
    }
        Tasks *task = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        detailVC.testTask = task;
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.detailViewsDictionary);
}
```

What I don't understand is...how would I access the timeInterval (each detailviewcontroller has a different timeinterval...) such that I can put it in `appliationDidEnterBackground`? Also, I am guessing I should save the time that the application enters the background and then save the time when it enters the foreground, and subtract? and then I would subtract that value from the timeinterval, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be using a direct countdown like this if you care at all about accuracy. The `NSTimer` will not fire on exact one-second intervals, and delays will accumulate. The better way to do this is to create an `NSDate` when the timer starts, and get the `NSTimeInterval` since then at each tick, then calculate the minutes and seconds.

For each view controller to store its own start time, you can register any object to receive the [`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification). This is posted at the same time that the app delegate gets `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

> Also, I am guessing I should save the time that the application enters the background and then save the time when it enters the foreground, and subtract? and then I would subtract that value from the timeinterval, correct?

Yes:

```
NSTimeInterval idleTime = [dateReturnedToForeground timeIntervalSinceDate:dateEnteredBackground];
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
elapsedTime -= idleTime;
```

will give you the *active* time that has elapsed for your timer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the first part. If I create the NSDate when the timer starts, what am I supposed to compare it to in the timerAction method to ensure that the timer works as is?

Comment: `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timerStartDate];`